# Issues with my jQuery match height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having issues with my jQuery match height... or maybe I just don't understand it fully? Any Help?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LzoL.png)

Image 1: This is how it looks without height matched, which i am happy with just some simple shadowed boxes. But they do not match each others height :/

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu8qn.png)

Image 2: This is how it looks currently when I am trying to apply my jQuery of match height. The shadowed boxes are tiny at the top and it pushes the content underneath them...

HTML:

```
<div class="column small-12 large-4 medium-12">
        <div class="home-card">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut accumsan, mi a auctor varius, nibh metus aliquet nisl, sit amet aliquam massa ipsum vitae magna. Praesent sed quam felis. Phasellus pretium tempus sapien, eu interdum turpis ultricies quis. Nam dictum nisl et nulla scelerisque venenatis. Fusce sit amet aliquam.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column small-12 large-4 medium-12">
        <div class="home-card">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <p>Vestibulum eget sodales orci. Quisque non semper enim. Mauris suscipit malesuada nisi sit amet tincidunt. Aliquam quam arcu, imperdiet ut tortor a, rhoncus aliquam leo. Nam ullamcorper elit vitae porttitor semper. Praesent cursus id felis nec eleifend. Ut vel sapien eleifend, efficitur metus eget, lacinia leo. Fusce eu lacus pretium, pulvinar tellus vel, vestibulum dui. Nunc congue libero justo, at aliquet ipsum posuere scelerisque. Praesent nunc lorem, venenatis eu velit sed, volutpat efficitur sem. Integer nisi arcu, sodales eu dignissim et, sagittis in massa. Aenean fringilla ante sed elit convallis, ac ornare urna porta. Pellentesque vel diam luctus, accumsan metus eu, malesuada elit.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column small-12 large-4 medium-12">
        <div class="home-card">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <p>Aenean a mi quis justo ultricies posuere nec vitae lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus nec felis ante. Nulla aliquet in augue id varius. Cras ut ligula a diam porta feugiat. Praesent dictum eros nisl, at interdum tellus suscipit vel. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fade").hide(0).delay(0).fadeIn(500)

$('div').each(function(){
    var highestBox = 0;
    
    $('.home-card', this).each(function(){
        if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
            highestBox = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $('.home-card', this).height(highestBox);
});
});
```

CSS:

```
    .home-card {
    box-shadow: 1px 0 11px rgba(33,33,33, 0.2);
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    width: 97%;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 0.5%;
}
.home-card:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 0 11px rgba(33,33,33, 0.4);
}
.home-card p, h2 {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Any Ideas?? Thanks!

ALSO: How would I get it so that height matches on large screens only, and is unaffected on medium and small screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the first `div` looping?

Just the second loop should do what you want.

```
var highestBox = 0;

$('.home-card').each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
        highestBox = $(this).height();
    }
});
$('.home-card').height(highestBox);
```

Because if there is another `div` having no `.home-card` child... Like a footer...
`highestBox` sets to 0.
Then all `.homecard` are setted to zero.

What you actually see as height probably is margin/padding of inner elements... or something.

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you mean, however doing as you said still gives me the same result. Thanks

Comment: The shadow... Is it applyed on `.home-card` or on `.column` ? It looks like applied on an element having nothing inside... Or having inner content overflowing.

Comment: I have `<div class="column small-12 large-4 medium-12">` nested inside that is `<div class="home-card">` and inside that is `<h2>` and `<p>`. The shadow is on the home-card.

Comment: I can see that from what you posted... But on which do you apply the CSS `box-shadow: XXpx XXpx XXpx #color` ?

Comment: Just updated my original post with the css for 'home-card', which is the class which contains the box shadow. Thanks

Comment: There is something missing to reproduce the columns display... I tried using Bootstrap 3 and 4. So I just added a column div wrapper and this CSS`.column{
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}` ... And the JS I suggest worked. See [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/RZgBQY)

Comment: It makes them all the same height upon load... But after resizing the page it pushes the text past below the text box? https://pasteboard.co/GFeWT2U.png

Seems to maintain the height of the boxes upon 1st load?

Comment: I just can't answer the last question. I don't know where is the nav bar and don't get where to place the 2 additionnal scrollbar you talk about.

Comment: Patrice Bassette, yeah man sorry I'm confusing you a bit now. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a CSS only solution?

You could wrap your columns in a container, let's use a div with a class of container. Make this container a flexbox container and child divs within it will be matching heights.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

I prefer using CSS for this type of problem because it's more of a presentational concern and this approach doesn't necessitate writing any messy javascript to manipulate the DOM. Additionally, unless you need to support old versions of IE, browser support for flexbox is pretty good. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

I added a border to the child divs with a class of column simply to illustrate that they are indeed the same height.

https://jsfiddle.net/eulloa/tx5jbdgf/1/

This is a pretty good reference on [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), in case you're interested in reading more.

Comment: Hi eulloa! Yep, did that and it looks the same as the original 'Image 1'. Don't know why, maybe its interfering with my CSS responsive grid?

Comment: @covert_supaman I hear ya... what you can do in in that case is define separate CSS rules that will effectively undo the flex rule we applied earlier using a media query. Read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: The idea would be to define a 'mobile' breakpoint, let's choose an arbitrary width of 320px. On mobile devices, or anywhere where the browser width is <= 320px, the new CSS rules you define in your media query would apply. Media queries are a great tool for adding responsiveness to your applications.

Comment: Doing something like this would fix the box height? I dont understand? I currently have a responsive grid and my navbar changes for small windows and screens... Unless that's what you are trying to tell me? Thanks for replying!